# como soluciono el error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, java-swing, joptionpane

Este es el error en sí, este aparece cuando presiono los botones de abajo, se supone que mande una ventanita con la respuesta, pero cada vez que lo trato de solucionar aparecen más error nuevo, este código se supone que muestre el resultado de la suma de ocupación de unas salas de cómputo, ya logre hacer la tabla y todo en interfaz de jpane, pero al presionar los botones me lanza el siguiente error que la verdad ya no sé cómo solucionar.

```
    at com.intro_java.TercerCorte.PreQuizGui.actionPerformed(PreQuizGui.java:123)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

** El codigo completo es:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PreQuizGui implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel titleLabel, subTitleLabel;
    JButton calculateButton, clearButton, maxButton, dayButton;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JComboBox<String> comboBox;

    int[][] Ocup = {
            {22, 19, 21, 15, 17},
            {25, 18, 20, 15, 23},
            {15, 13, 18, 12, 10},
            {30, 24, 23, 26, 29},
    };

    String[] columnNames = {"Sala", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Total"};
    String[][] rowData =
            {{"1", "22", "19", "21", "15", "17", ""},
                    {"2", "25", "18", "20", "15", "23", ""},
                    {"3", "15", "13", "18", "12", "10", ""},
                    {"4", "30", "24", "23", "26", "29", ""}};

    HashMap<String, Room> rooms = new HashMap<>();

    public PreQuizGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Ocupación semanal de las salas de computo");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(700, 550);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        titleLabel = new JLabel("Ocupación semanal de las salas de computo");
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        titleLabel.setBounds(140, 10, 400, 40);
        panel.add(titleLabel);

        subTitleLabel = new JLabel("Seleccione una sala para ver su ocupación");
        subTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        subTitleLabel.setBounds(190, 70, 300, 25);
        panel.add(subTitleLabel);

        comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Sala 1", "Sala 2", "Sala 3", "Sala 4"});
        comboBox.setBounds(300, 105, 100, 25);
        panel.add(comboBox);

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calcular");
        calculateButton.setBounds(175, 150, 100, 30);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(calculateButton);

        clearButton = new JButton("Limpiar");
        clearButton.setBounds(325, 150, 100, 30);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(clearButton);


        maxButton = new JButton("Calcular sala mas ocupada en la semana");
        maxButton.setBounds(20, 410, 270, 30);
        maxButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(maxButton);

        dayButton = new JButton("Calcular el dia de mas ocupacion");
        dayButton.setBounds(400, 410, 270, 30);
        dayButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(dayButton);


        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(40);
        table.setBounds(25, 200, 650, 200);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(25, 200, 650, 200);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int days = 0;
        int rooms = 5;

        if (e.getSource() == calculateButton) {
            String selectedSala = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();

            switch (selectedSala) {
                case "Sala 1" -> rowData[0][6] = String.valueOf(getTotalOcupacion(0));
                case "Sala 2" -> rowData[1][6] = String.valueOf(getTotalOcupacion(1));
                case "Sala 3" -> rowData[2][6] = String.valueOf(getTotalOcupacion(2));
                case "Sala 4" -> rowData[3][6] = String.valueOf(getTotalOcupacion(3));
                case "Sala 5" -> rowData[4][6] = String.valueOf(getTotalOcupacion(4));
            }

            table.repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
            clearTable();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == maxButton) {
            int maxUses = 0;
            String maxRoom = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
                int uses = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                    uses += Ocup[i][j];
                }
                if (uses > maxUses) {
                    maxUses = uses;
                    maxRoom = "Sala " + (i + 1);
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La sala más ocupada de la semana es " + maxRoom);

        }

        if (e.getSource() == dayButton) {
            int maxUses = 0;
            String maxDay = "";
            for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                int uses = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
                    uses += Ocup[i][j];
                }
                if (uses > maxUses) {
                    maxUses = uses;
                    switch (j) {
                        case 1 -> maxDay = "Lunes";
                        case 2 -> maxDay = "Martes";
                        case 3 -> maxDay = "Miércoles";
                        case 4 -> maxDay = "Jueves";
                        case 5 -> maxDay = "Viernes";
                    }
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hola prueba");
        }
    }

    public int getTotalOcupacion(int sala) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            total += Ocup[sala][j];
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void clearTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                rowData[i][j] = "";
            }
        }
        table.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PreQuizGui preQuiz1Gui = new PreQuizGui();
    }
}
```

este programa basicamente debe mostrar una GUI para calcular la ocupación semanal de las salas de ordenadores. El programa utiliza una matriz de enteros bidimensional para almacenar los datos de ocupación de cada sala, y una JTable para mostrar los datos en forma de tabla. La GUI incluye un cuadro combinado para seleccionar la sala, y dos botones para calcular la ocupación total de la sala seleccionada y para encontrar la sala con la mayor ocupación y el día con la mayor ocupación.

El programa comienza creando un JFrame y un JPanel, y estableciendo sus diseños en null. Luego añade varios componentes como JLabels, JButtons, JTable y un JComboBox al JPanel, y establece sus propiedades como fuente, tamaño y escuchadores de acciones. Finalmente, añade el JPanel al JFrame, establece el tamaño del JFrame y lo hace visible.

El método actionPerformed() es llamado cuando se pulsa un botón. Si se pulsa el botón "Calcular", el método obtiene la habitación seleccionada del cuadro combinado, calcula la ocupación total de esa habitación llamando al método getTotalOcupacion(), y actualiza la JTable con los nuevos datos. Si se pulsa el botón "Limpiar", el método llama al método clearTable() para borrar los datos de la JTable. Si se pulsa el botón "Calcular sala más ocupada en la semana", el método recorre todas las salas, calcula la ocupación total de cada sala y encuentra la sala con mayor ocupación. Por último, muestra un cuadro de mensaje con el resultado. Si se pulsa el botón "Calcular el día de mayor ocupación", el método recorre todos los días, calcula la ocupación total de cada día y busca el día de mayor ocupación. Por último, muestra un cuadro de mensaje con el resultado, pero los botones de abajo no funcionan porque me envian error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cuando das formato al código, debes agregar los backticks una línea _antes_ y una _después_ del código. Recién al editar el código uno se da cuenta que el verdadero error es `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. No olvides editar tu pregunta tanto para agregar el error en el título como para mostrarlo en el cuerpo de la misma.

Comment: Y por cierto... [¿Ya buscaste en el sitio?](/search?q=ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Answer (score 0):

tu código tiene algunos problemines.

La matriz **String[][] rowData**, tiene una fila menos de la que debe tener.

La matriz **int[][] Ocup**, tiene una fila menos de la que debe tener.

Dentro del if con la condición **e.getSource() == maxButton** tienes el segundo `for` así:

```
for( int j = 1; j < 6; j++ ) {
    uses += Ocup[ i ][ j ];
}
```

y deberías tener:

```
for( int j = 1; j < 5; j++ ) {
    uses += Ocup[ i ][ j ];
}
```

Dentro del `if` con la condición **e.getSource() == dayButton** tienes el primer `for` así:

```
for( int j = 1; j < 6; j++ ) {
    int uses = 0;
```

y deberías tener:

```
for( int j = 1; j < 5; j++ ) {
    int uses = 0;
```

Los errores dentro de los `for`, están generados por la forma en que codificas, lo menos propenso a errores (para recorrer un `array`) es usar **i < array.length**, de esa forma, aunque durante el proceso de crear tu programa, modifiques el tamaño del `array`, no tendrás errores.